# CollectionProxy object in rails 4?

Tags: activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I am using rails 4 and making an application in which Question_sets has many Questions and Questions has many answers. Now what i want is to update one attribute of question model and one attribute of answer model through questions sets.

```
       @question_set.questions.inspect
```

It gives the output

```
OUTPUT:

ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy 

[Question id: nil, title: "werewr", question_type: "Slider", description: "ewrewrew", is_shown_in_report: false, question_set_id: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil]
```

But when i am accessing any of the attribute or trying to update it, it will give an error that is undefined "attribute_name".

can any tell how to access the attributes of the this collectionproxy object.

Answer (score 3):

`questions` is returning a collection (like an Array) of Question objects. So you need to itterate over the collection:

```
@question_set.questions.each do |question|
  question.title
end
```